# Why isn't my mkl sparse matrix module working properly?

Tags: c++, intel-mkl

I first created a CSR matrix using the mkl sparse matrix module.
This part is normal and can be created.
Then I used mkl_sparse_s_add for matrix addition, and then the program reported an error.
The content of the error report is
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDA75F478C (KernelBase.dll) (in mkl.exe): 0xC06D007E: Module not found (parameter: 0x000000CEB30FF5B0).
Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mkl_spblas.h"
#include <mkl.h>

int main() {
    MKL_INT rowPtr[6] = { 0,3,5,8,11,13 };
    MKL_INT columns[13] = { 0,1,3,0,1,2,3,4,0,2,3,1,4 };
    float values[13] = { 1,-1,-3,-2,5,4,6,4,-4,2,7,8,-5 };
    sparse_matrix_t elementMatrix2; sparse_matrix_t elementMatrix3;
    mkl_sparse_s_create_csr(&elementMatrix2,SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO,5,5,rowPtr,rowPtr+1,columns,values);
    mkl_sparse_s_add(SPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, elementMatrix2, 1, elementMatrix2, &elementMatrix3);
}
```

Helps me run the program normally

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else who is looking into this with similar issues can refer to the Intel communities for the solution as this query has been addressed [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/Why-is-this-error-reported-Exception-thrown-at/m-p/1372342#M32946).
In this case, the issue got resolved after reinstalling the MKL.